# How to BEST extract information from multiple dataframes based on a series of if\else conditions and matching values? (Guidance needed!))

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, where-clause

So I have three Dataframes, X, Y and Events. df_X has X Co-ordinates, df_Y has Y Co-ordinates and Events_df has a list of events that has happened (The Data is Basketball related). You'll see how they link together by looking below:

```
df_Event:

Seconds Passed   Event Type         Player
1.0              Passed The Ball    Steve
2.0              Received Pass      Michael
3.0              Touch              Michael
4.0              Passed The Ball    Michael
5.0              Received The Ball  George


df_X:

Seconds Passed  Steve   Michael   George
1.0             11.43   12.33     15.33
2.0             11.45   12.46     13.22  
3.0             10.99   10.33     14.33           
4.0             11.34   10.36     11.22
5.0             12.43   12.22     11.78


df_Y:

....

(The Same As Above Just With Different Numbers)
```

I want to record patterns of events across time and then take the X, Y coordinates that correspond to the *Seconds Passed* columns across each Dataframes. So for example, if I wanted to know where a pass started and ended I would need the following information..

I want the following information in a new Dataframe labelled "Passes_df":

```
Passing Player   Receiving Player    X Coordinate PP   Y Coordinate PP  X Coordinate RP   Y Coordinate RP
Steve            Michael             11.43             ....             12.46             .....
```

I know I could use the following:

```
Passes_df['Passing Player'] = df_Event['Player'].where(df_Event['Event'] == 'Pass').dropna()
Passes_df['Receiving Player'] = df_Event['Player'].shift(-1).where\
((df_Event['Event'] == 'Pass') & (df_Event['Event'].shift(-1) == 'Received Pass'))
```

However, this seems way too long winded? Could I use a function that picks information from each source more fluently? Some help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pandas.pivot(...)` for this:

```py
#assuming it's sorted by Seconds Passed:
df_Event["Event_order"]=df_Event.groupby("Event Type").cumcount()

df_Event["X"]=df_Event.merge(df_X, on="Seconds Passed").apply(lambda x: x[x["Player"]], axis=1)
df_Event["Y"]=df_Event.merge(df_Y, on="Seconds Passed").apply(lambda x: x[x["Player"]], axis=1)

df=df_Event.pivot(index="Event_order", columns="Event Type", values=["Player", "X", "Y"])

#to flatten columns index:
df.columns=map(lambda x: "_".join(x), df.columns)
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution to the question needs a systematic approach which would affect significantly if understaning of problem changes. Since in the asked question, the output dataframe has excluded event type 'Touch' and has only compared Passes and Receiving; therefore, I have adopted the approach to reach at such output.

1. X and Y cordinates dataframes are untidy. We need to bring them in tidy form through pd.melt function.
2. Merge event, X cordinates and Y cordinates data into a single dataframe through pd.merge function.
3. Create separate dataframe of passes and receivings.
4. Since 'Seconds Passed' is unique column, I'm assuming there is 1 second lag in passing and receiving. Therefore, remove 1 second from receiving dataframe.
5. Merge passes dataframe with receiving dataframe.

(P.S: As convention, I used pd instead of pandas)

## Step 1: Bring the data in tidy form

```
tidy_x = pd.melt(df_x, id_vars='Seconds Passed', var_name='Player', value_name='X_Cordinate')
tidy_y = pd.melt(df_y, id_vars='Seconds Passed', var_name='Player', value_name='Y_Cordinate')
tidy_y['Y_Cordinate'] += 10 # Hypothetical number to change numbers from X.
```

## Step 2: Merge event, X cordinates and Y cordinates data into a single dataframe

```
df = pd.merge(df_event, tidy_x)
df = pd.merge(df, tidy_y)
```

Now you have comprehensive data of event with coordinates and player.

## Step 3: Create separate dataframe of passes and receivings.

```
passes = df['Event Type'].str.startswith('Pass')
df_passes = df[passes].copy()

received = df['Event Type'].str.startswith('Received')
df_received = df[received].copy()
df_received.loc[received, 'Seconds Passed'] -= 1
```

## Finally: Merge passes dataframe with receiving dataframe.

```
pd.merge(df_passes, df_received, on='Seconds Passed', suffixes=('_PP', '_RP'))
```

## Result/ Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. If I wanted to record X and Y cordinates in between when the ball was 'passed' and 'received'. How would you go about this? Some I always want to look at some series of events and grab the coordinates between the Seconds passed. So looking at your example, between 1 and 4 Seconds passed how would I get the coordinates?

Comment: @Sam if you want to maintain the sequence of events as shown in df_event then in the last step used 'df' instead of 'df_passes' with left join parameters. If you like my answer, please mark it as answer.

Comment: @HussainMansoor reducing `Seconds Passed` of `df_received` by 1 - is it because in the example data both passes are received in next second? What if there is longer time gap between passing and receiving?

Comment: @ckedar real life data could have many issues including the one you mentioned which would impact the approach.

Comment: @HussainMansoor Yes, that's it. Would there be a way to do this. For instance is a player dribbles the ball? I want to extract this information

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

```
df_X:
   Seconds  Steve  Michael  George
0      1.0  11.43    12.33   15.33
1      2.0  11.45    12.46   13.22
2      3.0  10.99    10.33   14.33
3      4.0  11.34    10.36   11.22
4      5.0  12.43    12.22   11.78

df_e:
   Seconds     Event   Player
0      1.0    Passed    Steve
1      2.0  Received  Michael
2      3.0     Touch  Michael
3      4.0    Passed  Michael
4      5.0  Received   George
```

and df_Y is similar to df_X.

First unstack df_X and df_Y and join them with df_E to get all info in single df.

```
df_X = df_X.set_index('Seconds').stack().rename_axis(['Seconds', 'Player']).rename('X')
df_Y = df_Y.set_index('Seconds').stack().rename_axis(['Seconds', 'Player']).rename('Y')
df_e = df_e.set_index(['Seconds', 'Player'])
df_e = df_e.join(df_X).join(df_Y).reset_index(level='Player')

df_e:
          Player     Event      X      Y
Seconds                                 
1.0        Steve    Passed  11.43  11.43
2.0      Michael  Received  12.46  12.46
3.0      Michael     Touch  10.33  10.33
4.0      Michael    Passed  10.36  10.36
5.0       George  Received  11.78  11.78
```

Now select only pass related events, i.e. `Passed` and `Received`

```
df_pe = df_e[df_e.Event.isin(['Passed', 'Received'])]
```

Join the consecutive events:

```
df_pe = df_pe.join(df_pe.shift(-1), rsuffix='_1')
```

and then retain only the passes that were 'Received'

```
df_passes = df_pe[df_pe.Event_1 == 'Received']

          Player   Event      X      Y Player_1   Event_1    X_1    Y_1
Seconds                                                                
1.0        Steve  Passed  11.43  11.43  Michael  Received  12.46  12.46
4.0      Michael  Passed  10.36  10.36   George  Received  11.78  11.78
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want information about "how the ball moved" including dribbling you could do the following:

## 0: I simplified the input a bit:

```
d_e = {'seconds':[1,2,3,4,5], 'event' : ['passed', 'received', 'touch', 'passed', 'received'], 'player' : ['Steve', 'Michael','Michael','Michael','George']}
d_x = {'seconds':[1,2,3,4,5], 'Steve': [11.43, 11.45, 10.99, 11.34, 12.43], 'Michael':[12.33, 12.46, 10.33, 10.36, 12.22], 'George': [15.33, 13.22, 14.33, 11.22, 11.78]}
d_y = {'seconds':[1,2,3,4,5], 'Steve': [13.43, 13.45, 12.99, 12.34, 12.00], 'Michael':[9.33, 9.46, 10.53, 12.36, 12.72], 'George': [10.33, 10.22, 10.33, 11.72, 12.78]}
df_e = pd.DataFrame(d_e)
df_x = pd.DataFrame(d_x)
df_y = pd.DataFrame(d_y)
```

## 1: Merge X and Y to tuples for coordinates:

Of course you don't have to use tuples and can stick with a solution like given by @ckedar, adjust keys later on accordingly.

```
df_merged = df_x.merge(df_y, on=['seconds']).set_index('seconds')
df_merged=df_merged.groupby(df_merged.columns.str.split('_').str[0],axis=1).agg(lambda x : tuple(x.tolist()))
```

Result:

```
                 George         Michael           Steve
seconds                                                
1        (15.33, 10.33)   (12.33, 9.33)  (11.43, 13.43)
2        (13.22, 10.22)   (12.46, 9.46)  (11.45, 13.45)
3        (14.33, 10.33)  (10.33, 10.53)  (10.99, 12.99)
4        (11.22, 11.72)  (10.36, 12.36)  (11.34, 12.34)
5        (11.78, 12.78)  (12.22, 12.72)   (12.43, 12.0)
```

## 2: Put coordinates in Event dataframe:

```
df_e['coord'] = df_e.apply(lambda x : df_merged.loc[x['seconds']][x['player']]  ,axis=1)
```

Result:

```
   seconds     event   player           coord
0        1    passed    Steve  (11.43, 13.43)
1        2  received  Michael   (12.46, 9.46)
2        3     touch  Michael  (10.33, 10.53)
3        4    passed  Michael  (10.36, 12.36)
4        5  received   George  (11.78, 12.78)
```

## 3: Create new df with "from" and "to" information:

Here you would have to adjust to different keys, if you are not using tuples as coords, but rather X and Y.

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['second', 'from', 'to', 'from_coord', 'to_coord'])
df_new[['second', 'from', 'from_coord']] = df_e[['seconds', 'player', 'coord']].iloc[:-1]
df_new[['to', 'to_coord']] = df_e[['player', 'coord']].iloc[1:].reset_index().drop('index',axis=1)
df_new = df_new.set_index('second')
```

Result:

```
           from       to      from_coord        to_coord
second                                                  
1         Steve  Michael  (11.43, 13.43)   (12.46, 9.46)
2       Michael  Michael   (12.46, 9.46)  (10.33, 10.53)
3       Michael  Michael  (10.33, 10.53)  (10.36, 12.36)
4       Michael   George  (10.36, 12.36)  (11.78, 12.78)
```

## 4 (optional): Now you can get passes and dribbling:

```
print('Passes:')
print(df_new[df_new['from'] != df_new['to']])
print('Dribbling:')
print(df_new[df_new['from'] == df_new['to']])
```

Result:

```
Passes:
           from       to      from_coord        to_coord
second                                                  
1         Steve  Michael  (11.43, 13.43)   (12.46, 9.46)
4       Michael   George  (10.36, 12.36)  (11.78, 12.78)

Dribbling:
           from       to      from_coord        to_coord
second                                                  
2       Michael  Michael   (12.46, 9.46)  (10.33, 10.53)
3       Michael  Michael  (10.33, 10.53)  (10.36, 12.36)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem lacks some description - you're using 'Event' column and matching 'Pass', when the values are different in data. Shift Operation used twice is probably not recommended here, but using it once is probably okay (can still be improved though):

```
Passes_df = df_Event.copy()

Passes_df['X_Coordinate_PP'] = Passes_df.apply(lambda x: df_X.loc[df_X['Seconds Passed'] == x['Seconds_Passed']][x['Player']], axis=1)

Passes_df['Y_Coordinate_PP'] = Passes_df.apply(lambda x: df_Y.loc[df_Y['Seconds Passed'] == x['Seconds_Passed']][x['Player']], axis=1)

Passes_df['Passing Player'] = Passes_df.apply(lambda x: x['Player'] if x['Event Type'].contains('Pass') else None)

Passes_df['Receiving Player'] = Passes_df.apply(lambda x: x['Player'] if x['Event Type'].contains('Receive') else None)

Passes_df['X_Coordinate_RP'] = Passes_df['X_Coordinate_PP'].shift(-1)
Passes_df['Y_Coordinate_RP'] = Passes_df['Y_Coordinate_PP'].shift(-1)

Passes_df.drop(columns=['Player'], inplace=True)
Passes_df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Let me know if this helps!